# How to reset react-select value via state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Feeding the react-select component the selected state to the value prop, makes it unable to select anything at all? I'm trying to feed the value-prop with the selected state so that i can reset react-select via setState. What am i doing wrong here?

Select Component with isMulti option:

```
import SelectForm from "react-select";

const Select = (props) => {
  const options = props.options.map((option) => ({
    value: option,
    label: option.toLowerCase(),
  }));

  const costumStyles = {
    container: (baseStyles) => ({ ...baseStyles, width: "100%" }),
    control: (baseStyles) => ({
      ...baseStyles,
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      borderStyle: "none",
      borderRadius: "15px",
      marginTop: "3px",
    }),
    singleValue: (baseStyles) => ({ ...baseStyles, color: "white" }),
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.onChangeOption(event);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        {props.isMulti ? (
          <SelectForm
            options={options}
            onChange={handleChange}
            styles={costumStyles}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            value={props.value}
            isMulti
          />
        ) : (
          <SelectForm
            options={options}
            onChange={handleChange}
            styles={costumStyles}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            value={props.value}
          />
        )}
      </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

The parent component which uses the Select component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Select from "../../input/Select";

const CreateJobPage3 = (props) => {
  const [department, setDepartment] = useState();
  const [subDepartment, setSubDepartment] = useState([]);

  const departments = [jobDepartment1, jobDepartment2, jobDepartment3];

  const subDepartments = [jobSubDepartment1, jobSubDepartment2, jobSubDepartment3];

  const departmentHandler = (props) => {
    setDepartment(props.value);
    setSubDepartment([]);
  };

  const subDepartmentHandler = (props) => {
    setSubDepartment(props.map((item) => item.value));
  };

  return (
    <>
        <Select
          placeholder="Choose Department"
          options={departments}
          onChangeOption={departmentHandler}
          value={department || ""}
        />
        <Select
          placeholder="Choose Sub-Departments"
          options={subDepartments}
          onChangeOption={subDepartmentHandler}
          isMulti={true}
          value={subDepartment || ""}
        />
    </>
  );
};

export default CreateJobPage3;
```

Comment: You are not passing value prop inside `Select` component if `isMulti` .

Comment: Also, you are passing `onChangeOption` a event. So in `departmentHandler` shouldn't it be event.target.value ? are you getting the expected value by using `props.value` ?

Comment: Right, i wasn't passing it because i was testing - still can't choose an option on the select component with the value prop on though. And yes, i'm getting the expected value by using props.value

Comment: The setState is updating correctly - only the select component does not show the state passed through value. It shows nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs of `react-select` they're expecting complete option to be passed in value array.

Say for example, we have options like

```
const options=[
   { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true },
   { value: 'red', label: 'Red', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true }
];
```

then we have to pass value as,

```
value={[{ value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true }]}
```

Refer this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/17g0yy?module=/example.tsx

Try this,

```
const departmentHandler = (props) => {
  setDepartment(props);
  setSubDepartment([]);
};

const subDepartmentHandler = (props) => {
  setSubDepartment(props);
};
```

Comment: I found the solution, however it only works on single select, and not when multi: 

value={options.filter(function (option) {
              return option.value === props.value;
            })}

What would be the equivalent of this for an array, which is what the isMulti is receiving?

Comment: You dont need to filter it separately. in your `onChangeOption` you will be receiving the selected options with its props. You can use it as i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: if you use `isMulti` then your `onChangeOption` handler (subDepartmentHandler) will be getting array of selected options. if `isMulti` is not used, your handler (departmentHandler) will receive selected object.

Comment: No that solution does not work. The value prop apparently expects an object with a value and a label, hence why the filtering method works, and the props.value does not.

Comment: Aah sorry, i didn't read your answer correctly, you're completely right! Thank you